# PIVOT. Use rows as column name and fill records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pivot, multiple-columns

I have 2 tables `FormFields` and `Values`. I need to select rows from `FormFields` table and set as column names. After It should fill these columns with values from `Values` table. `Values` have `GroupId` each group should be in new row (where `GroupId = 1` should fill first row, where `GroupId = 2` should fill second row and etc.)

FormFields table:

```
Id   GroupId     Name
1       1       Examp11       
2       1       Examp12  
3       1       Examp13   
4       1       Examp14   
5       1       Examp15   
6       1       Examp16 
7       2       Examp17  -- End of the group 1    
8       2       Examp11  -- From here should start second row (after pivot)
9       2       Examp12   
10      2       Examp13   
11      2       Examp14   
12      2       Examp15 
13      2       Examp16 
14      2       Examp17 -- End of the group 2
```

Values table:

```
Id   GroupId   FormFieldId   Value
18       1           1        val1
19       1           2        val2
20       1           3        val3
21       1           4        val4   
22       1           5        val5   
23       1           6        val6
24       1           7        val7 
25       2           1        val8 -- From here start duplicating FormFieldId, changed GroupId to 2
26       2           2        val9
27       2           3        val10   
28       2           4        val11   
29       2           5        val12
30       2           6        val13
31       2           7        val14
```

It should be selected as (by GroupId, where `GroupId = 1` values should go to first row, where `GroupId = 2` values should go to second row and etc). In this example I show you only 14 values, but at all I have 28 values (in 4 groups) to select:

```
Examp11  Examp12  Examp13  Examp14  Examp15  Examp16  Examp17       
  val1     val2     val3     val4     val5     val6     val7  -- GroupId = 1
  val8     val9     val10    val11    val12    val13    val4  -- GroupId = 2
```

I know that I need to use `PIVOT`, but can't make It successfully.

I've tried this, but It throws error that

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols = 'SELECT [Name] FROM FormFields WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 6'
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM FormFields
) x
PIVOT
(
    MIN (Name)
    FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
) p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it as `Dynamic query` to use `@cols`(columns).

Also I made changes to the column list `@cols` generation

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='',
        @sql  NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @cols += Isnull([Name], '') + ','
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT name
        FROM   FormFields
        WHERE  ID BETWEEN 1 AND 6)a 


SET @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)
SET @sql=' SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT v.GroupId, Name,Value
    FROM FormFields F join Values V on F.id= v.FormFieldId
) x PIVOT
(
    MIN (Value)
    FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
) p'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. It successfully returns rows as column names, but how to make second part of question, to fill these columns with values from `Values` table?

Comment: @Infinity - Just `join` the `values` table. Updated check now

Comment: Thank you for an answer. For now If I change `WHERE range` up to `BETWEEN 1 AND 28` I got following error: `The column 'Examp11' was specified multiple times for 'p'.` Maybe that because where `FormFieldId = 7` is duplicate value as `FormFieldId =1`, but I need add duplicates too as column names Or It's impossible?

Comment: @Infinity - Updated check now

Comment: If column names can't duplicate, I updated my question with how to make It

Comment: @Infinity - see the answer. I have used distinct try now

Comment: I've tried It, now It not throw error, but still returning only 7 columns, not all 28 (that because It have duplicating. I need duplicates as column names or better way to make how I shown in edited question. For now I understand that column names can't have duplicates, so only 1 way to make It Is how I shown in edited question or renaming duplicated column names as Examp11+1.

Comment: Edited my question with more info. Chek It, please.

Comment: Have you any ideas how to make It?

Comment: @Infinity - updated check now. Was little busy thats why couldn't reply

Comment: I think did you meant `join Values` instead of `join #Values`. SOmething wrong with that. It returning now GroupId column too where It going from 1 to 15 (at all 15 rows), in first 4 rows are `0` (that because my values are `0` or `1`) and in other rows all values are `null`

Comment: Have you idea why It returning for me 15 lines instead of 4?

Comment: @Infinity - You might have selected unwanted columns in `pivot` source query that is in that `join` query

Comment: Thank you very much, now left 1 problem. I'm using all this code in stored procedure with input parameters and I have problem. In your code (in `WHERE clause`) I used some `@parameters`. This `EXEC Sp_executesql @sql ` is executed inside other Stored Procedure(for ex.: sp_Example). So sp_Example have  `input @parameters` which should go in part of code which you wrote. But Problem is that when `EXEC Sp_executesql @sql ` is executed, It not see @parameters anymore, have you ideas how to fix It?

Comment: @Infinity - Sorry i need more info on that procedure with proper demo of your problem. May be a new question